# Adding another MediaType to REST api endpoint that is used by other clients

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

In my app I am sharing REST api using Spring MVC, which users may use in their custom apps. Let's say I have an endpoint in Controller class:

```
@GET
@Path("/getNumber")
@Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
public String getNumber(Long id) {
    return service.getNumber(id);
}
```

which response is available only as TEXT_PLAIN. What would happen, if for example one of the client say that his app will not work when he gets response as plain text and that the endpoint should return json/or should have possibility to return response in json? So when I add another MediaType to annotation @Produces, may that cause problems with other users custom apps using this endpoint? Because for ex. in their apps, client may be expecting response as plain text, and by getting response as json, response will not be handled correctly?
If adding this MediaType may cause problems, what can I do to take into account users custom apps using this endpoint? Should I create similar endpoint, but this one will have MediaType APPLICATION_JSON, or both, with added for ex. "/v2" in endpoint path, or is there some better solution for that?

```
@GET
@Path("/v2/getNumber")
@Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public String getNumber(Long id) {
    return service.getNumber(id);
}
```

Comment: The fact that your clients are expecting to get served with a particular media type by default is already a smell that you don't really operate on REST premises. In a REST architecture there would be content-type negotiation going on. [Spring MVC](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-content-negotiation-json-xml) does support that though I wouldn't aim for the URL suffix matching strategy and go for the ACCEPT header only as this allows to pass a list of content-types your client is able to process, including a preference indicator.

Answer (score 0):

No need to create multiple endpoints. You can define multiple mediaTypes in @Produces.

Inorder to decide which MediaType should be sent as response, Client has to set the type of MediaType they are expecting in the "Accept" header when making the request.

Based on this "Accept" header you can decide what content-type to return.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **"consume"** keyword for Multiple media type

```
@GET(value = "/configuration", consumes = {
MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE
})
public String setConfiguration(@RequestPart MultipartFile file, 
@RequestBody Configuration configuration)
```